# copy a SQL database from one server to another server on IBM netezza Aginity workbench

Tags: sql, database, windows-7, netezza

I need to copy a sql database from one server to another server on IBM netezza Aginity workbench.

I know how to do it in MS SQL server.

But, I am not familiar with IBM netezza.

Do I need to copy the database to a local drive and then copy it to the target server from the local drive ?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [`WinSQL`](http://web.synametrics.com/netezzatosqlserver.htm) to map the fields from your `MS SQL Server` to your `Netezza` Server.   From there you would need to dump out all your data in `SQL Server` using [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) one table at a time.  Then use [Netezza Transient External Tables](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_transient_external_tables.html) or [NZload](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_nzload_command.html) to load to the new box.